# best way to hide and show multiple lines of text (like help) in a VisualBasic2010 web app

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

In a VisualBasic2010 web app, which control in the toolbox should I use to display and hide a multi-line block of text on the page?

I will have a linkbutton called 'hide' following the next, and when the user clicks it, the .visible property of the text will be set false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with making html server-side tag like

```
<div class="tooltip" runat="server" ID="myTooltip" Visible="true">Some multiline text</div>
```

and change it visible property in code behind.

```
linkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 myTooltip.Visible = false;
}
```

Very basic solution, but works great for me.

Other option is that you can use Tooltip control aswell.